# MapFragment returns Null

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I have an activity and MapFragment Class.I have created MapFragment Object in Activity.When I tried to get mapFragmentObject.getView() it is returning Null.But i have created MapFragment like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    mapView = ((MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map));

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setMapView();

    return view;
}

public void setMapView() {
    try {

        map = mapView.getMap();

        map.clear();

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        MapData mapData = MapData.getInstance();
        Double[][] latlang = mapData.getLatlang();
        String[] WONum = mapData.getWOnum();
        marker = new Marker[mapData.getLatlang().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mapData.getLatlang().length; i++) {
            this.marker[i] = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latlang[i][0], latlang[i][1]))
                    .title(" ").snippet(" " + WONum[i] + "\n"));
            builder.include(this.marker[i].getPosition());
        }

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 60,
                60, 1);
        map.animateCamera(cu);

        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {

                if (position.zoom > 12.0f) {
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f));
                } else if (position.zoom < 2.0f) {
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4.0f));
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

And i am calling from Activity is like 
in OnCreate

```
WOLocator locator = new WOLocator();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(locator, "Map").commit();
setContentView(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Map").getView());
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually one I have had a problem with too, the issue is caused as the map is not initialised at the point you are currently trying to request it. The map process takes a while longer than a standard view set up.

There are some listeners you can set up to fire once it is ready but I have found it quite reliable to use the onActivityCreated function of your map fragment (mine extends SupportMapFragment).

So for your example I would try moving your setMapView() function call to the onActivityCreated function of your fragment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I was successfully able to access a map's view on @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) { }

Answer (score 0):

```
in layout activity_main.xml

     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapEditView"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

in java file

```
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
LatLng CENTER = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = null;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,
                false);
    CENTER = new LatLng(latitudeDoubleValue, longitudeDoubleValue);

    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapEditView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setMapView();
}



 private void setMapView() {
    if (mapView != null) {
        locationManager = ((LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));

        locListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Boolean localBoolean = Boolean.valueOf(locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled("network"));

        if (localBoolean.booleanValue()) {

            CENTER = new LatLng(latitudeDouble, longitudeDouble);
            GetCityNameFromLatitudeLongitude getCityName = new GetCityNameFromLatitudeLongitude(
                    getActivity());
            locationString = getCityName.getCityNameFromLatitudeLongitude(
                    CENTER.latitude, CENTER.longitude);
        } else {

        }
        map = mapView.getMap();
        if (map == null) {
            Log.d("----------->>>",
                    "Map Fragment Not Found or no Map in it!!");
            return;
        }

        map.clear();
        try {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CENTER)
                    .title(locationString).snippet(""));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        map.setIndoorEnabled(true);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5));
        if (CENTER != null) {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(CENTER), 1750,
                    null);
        }
        // add circle
        CircleOptions circle = new

        CircleOptions();

        circle.center(CENTER).fillColor(Color.BLUE).radius(10);

        map.addCircle(circle);
        // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    }
}
```